List directories and files at specific depth, when file paths are given in a text file
I am given a text file (filelist.txt) which lists all the files on a computer.
It looks something like this:
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-04-29 10:00 home/Desktop/
lrwxrwxrwx user1/user1       0 2024-08-13 10:00 home/Desktop/file0
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-14 11:00 home/Documents/
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-15 11:00 home/Documents/dir1/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-16 12:00 home/Documents/dir1/dirA/file1
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-17 12:00 home/Documents/dir2/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-18 11:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file2
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-19 11:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file3
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file4

I would like to list directories and files that are at certain depth.
Let's say, I would like to list what are right below 'Documents' and the ideal output would be something like below:
home/Documents/dir1/
home/Documents/dir2/
home/Documents/dir3/

or something below is fine too:
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-15 11:00 home/Documents/dir1/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-17 12:00 home/Documents/dir2/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-17 12:00 home/Documents/dir3/

I have tried with grep like this but nothing came out:
grep 'home\/Documents\/[^\/]\/$ filelist.txt

Any idea?
I'm using Mac terminal, but any solution using Mac terminal or python would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Your input file looks like the output of ls in which case you may have a problem, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Can't some of your file names include white space (or even newlines)?

There's no dir3 in your sample input but there is in your expected output - please [edit] your question to fix or explain that.

You can use awk:
$ awk '$6 ~ "^home/Documents/.+" {if (split($6, arr, "/") <= 4) {print $6}}' filelist.txt
home/Documents/dir1/
home/Documents/dir2/
home/Documents/FILE

The last line shows that this method works correctly with files, that is with lines that do not have a terminating '/':
$ tail -n1 filelist.txt
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-15 11:00 home/Documents/FILE


Thank you very much! This worked.

If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see What should I do when someone
answers my question?

Regarding your original code
grep 'home\/Documents\/[^\/]\/$ filelist.txt

firstly you are missing ending ' thus it is waiting to be closed, after fixing that
grep 'home\/Documents\/[^\/]\/$' filelist.txt

will give empty output, because [^\/] denotes single character, you should add * to express zero-or-more times following way
grep 'home\/Documents\/[^\/]*\/$' filelist.txt

then for filelist.txt content be
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-04-29 10:00 home/Desktop/
lrwxrwxrwx user1/user1       0 2024-08-13 10:00 home/Desktop/file0
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-14 11:00 home/Documents/
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-15 11:00 home/Documents/dir1/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-16 12:00 home/Documents/dir1/dirA/file1
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-17 12:00 home/Documents/dir2/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-18 11:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file2
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-19 11:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file3
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file4

output will be
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-15 11:00 home/Documents/dir1/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-17 12:00 home/Documents/dir2/

with paths being colored by default

I get grep: warning: stray \ before / warning 3 times. Additionally, the solution will won't work with hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1 0 2024-08-15 11:00 home/Documents/FILE, IOW in all lines
that do not have / at the end.

I add some more lines to file like this
$ cat filelist.txt
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-04-29 10:00 home/Desktop/
lrwxrwxrwx user1/user1       0 2024-08-13 10:00 home/Desktop/file0
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-14 11:00 home/Documents/
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-15 11:00 home/Documents/dir1/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-16 12:00 home/Documents/dir1/dirA/file1
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-17 12:00 home/Documents/dir2/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-18 11:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file2
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-19 11:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file3
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file4
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/file5
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/dir_Y/file_a
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/dir_Y/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/file_123
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/dir_Y/file_b
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/dir_X/file_c

I then allow search on different strings like this where I have to provide value for name on command line and I only match on whole words
$ cat file.awk
{
        count = split($6, a, "/")
        for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                if (a[i] == name) {
                        if (count - i == 1 && a[count] != "") {
                                print
                        } else if (count - i == 2 && a[count] == "") {
                                print
                        }
                }
        }
}

I then run with different names
for name in Documents Docu Documents2 dir2 dirB dir_X dir_Y; do
    echo "::::::: $name"
    awk -f file.awk -v name="$name" filelist.txt
done

::::::: Documents
hrw-rw-r-- user1/user1       0 2024-08-15 11:00 home/Documents/dir1/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-17 12:00 home/Documents/dir2/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/file5
::::::: Docu
::::::: Documents2
::::::: dir2
::::::: dirB
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-18 11:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file2
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-19 11:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file3
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir2/dirB/file4
::::::: dir_X
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/dir_Y/
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/file_123
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/dir_X/file_c
::::::: dir_Y
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/dir_Y/file_a
-rw-rw-r-- user1/user1    2160 2024-08-20 10:00 home/Documents/dir_X/dir_Y/file_b


You could do this using any sed and sort:
$ sed -n 's:.* \(home/Documents/[^/]*/\).*:\1:p' file | sort -u
home/Documents/dir1/
home/Documents/dir2/

but it'll fail (produce undesirable output) if you have input like home/Desktop/ home/Documents/dir/. I suspect all other answers will fail too given various possible inputs other than those in the sample input in the question.
Regarding the grep command from the question:

grep 'home\/Documents\/[^\/]\/$ filelist.txt


It's missing the terminating ' for the regexp, which I assume is a typo.
/ isn't a regexp metacharacter so you shouldn't escape it in a regexp as that turns it into undefined behavior. You need to escape it in some tools which use / as a regexp delimiter to accommodate that tools syntax (or use a different delimiter), but grep isn't one of those tools.
[^/] means exactly 1 non-/ character. You want to allow for 1 or more so you'd need to add some kind of repetition instruction, e.g. add + to the regexp and add the -E option to enable EREs since + is an ERE metachar.
The $ on the end anchors it to only match lines that end with / but that's not what your input/output show you want so get rid of that $.

Given the above your grep command should have been written:
grep -E 'home/Documents/[^/]+/' filelist.txt

I'm not suggesting that will work, just that it's the right syntax for the command the OP wrote.
